# android prevent popstack on backbutton pressed

Tags: android, back-button

I am creating an application which has a drawer layout. I have a fragments which replace the layout in the activity_main.When the back button is pressed and if the drawer is open , I want only the drawer to be closed but not the fragment.How can I accomplish that.Here is the java code of MainActivty where I call onBackPressed().
MainActivity.java:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove super.OnbackPressed() and write this.

```
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
           // super.onBackPressed();
            yourDrawerLayoutObject.hideNavigationDrawer();
         }
```

And in your navigationDrawerFragment write this method:

```
       public void hideNavigationDrawer(){
             mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
       }
```

Comment: if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            //drawer is open
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();}

Comment: I have added the above code to onBackpressed method.It works

Comment: But the fragment in the main activity is also being popped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (slidingDrawer.isOpened())
        slidingDrawer.close();
    else
        super.onBackPressed(); 
}
```

Hope it helps;)